# select the perticular object from for loop in views.py django

Tags: python, django

I want select one by one object from for loop in django views.py

views.py

```
crave = CraveData.objects.filter(person=request.user.id)
    for crave1 in crave:
        #print crave1
        check = Comment.objects.filter(crave=crave1)
```

comment.model.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    comment_owener = models.ForeignKey(User)
    crave=models.ForeignKey(CraveData, blank = True,null = True)
    reply=models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank = True,null = True)
    unique_id= models.IntegerField(max_length=50, blank = True,null = True)
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.reply
```

crave.model.py

```
class CraveData(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post=models.TextField(blank = True,null = True)

    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post
```

while printing the crave1 i am getting all objects in crave data which are associated with that particular user. Here i am getting the print result for crave1 is Post1, Post2.
Here i want to select each crave so i can assign the related comments to that crave. In this case i want to select the post1 so i i can assign the comments related to post1 to itself.
and i want to do this for all craves available for that user.

i tried here by using

```
crave1.check=Comment.objects.filter(crave=crave1)
```

so i am getting this reply

```
[<Comment: reply1>, <Comment: Reply1.1>, <Comment: reply1.3>]
[<Comment: reply2>]
```

But

```
[<Comment: reply1>, <Comment: Reply1.1>, <Comment: reply1.3>]
```

this comments are associated with post1 and

```
[<Comment: reply2>]
```

this comment is associated with post2 crave.

comment.html

```
<p><strong>{{user.username}} said:</strong></p><br>
                        {% for crave1 in crave %}

                        {{crave1}}<br>
                        {% for pf in check%}
                     {{pf.reply}}<br>
                     {% endfor %}

                     {% endfor %}
```

So result of all this in browser is 
admin said:

Post1
reply2
post2
reply2

Basically i want to display the post and its related comments for that particular user.
Please help me for this.

Comment: Please show your model definitions.

Comment: Hay alecxe , i edited the queston,,,,,

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the reverse foreign key relationship like so:

```
{% for crave1 in crave %}
   {{crave1}}<br>
   {% for comment in crave1.comment_set.all }}
       {{comment.reply}}<br>
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here are the docs for it.
[related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) and [reverse relationships.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)